# Adding checkbox with multiple value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a set of books in checkboxes which a user can select. Every time a book is checked the price adds up. I also need to add its corresponding weight. I've modified [this very useful example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21442833/javascript-add-checkbox-checked-values) but to no avail.

```
<label class="checkbox" for="Checkbox1">
<input value="50" type="checkbox" class="sum" data-toggle="checkbox"> Instagram
</label>
<label class="checkbox">
    <input value="50" bweight=".4"  type="checkbox" class="sum" data-toggle="checkbox"> Review site monitoring
</label>
<label class="checkbox">
    <input value="30" bweight=".2" type="checkbox" class="sum" data-toggle="checkbox"> Google+
</label>
<label class="checkbox">
    <input value="20" bweight=".6"  type="checkbox" class="sum" data-toggle="checkbox"> LinkedIn
</label>

<div class="card-charge-info">
    <span id="payment-total">0</span>
</div>
```

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum'),
    total  = document.getElementById('payment-total');
    totwgt = document.getElementById('payment-w');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].onchange = function() {
        var add = this.value * (this.checked ? 1 : -1);
        var add = this.wgt * (this.checked ? 1 : -1);
        total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML) + add
        totwgt.innerHTML = parseFloat(total1.innerHTML) + add
    }
}
```

Heres the code https://jsfiddle.net/u8bsjegk/2/

Answer (score 1):

There's several issues in your code. Firstly you define the `add` variable in two places, one for the value the other for weight so your calculation is broken from there. Also note that `bweight` is not a valid attribute on the `input` element. To add your own meta data you should use a `data-*` attribute instead.

Try this:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum'),
    totalValue = document.getElementById('payment-total'),
    totalWeight = document.getElementById('payment-w');


for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].onchange = function() {
        var value = parseFloat(this.value);
        var weight = parseFloat(this.dataset.weight);

        totalValue.innerHTML = parseFloat(totalValue.innerHTML) + value
        totalWeight.innerHTML = parseFloat(totalWeight.innerHTML) + weight
    }
}
```

As you've tagged this question with jQuery, here's a working implementation for that

```
var $inputs = $('.sum'),
    $totalValue = $('#payment-total'),
    $totalWeight = $('#payment-w');

$inputs.change(function() {
    var value = parseFloat(this.value);
    var weight = parseFloat($(this).data('weight'));

    $totalValue.text(function(i, text) {
        return parseFloat(text) + value;
    });
    $totalWeight.text(function(i, text) {
        return parseFloat(text) + weight;
    });
})
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/u8bsjegk/5/)

Comment: An explanation of the downvote would be helpful. Did I miss something, or is there an error in my examples?

Comment: Downvoting muppets! Does that `dataset` thing work?  I had a look at it but couldn't get it to work so looked it up and it said there was some issues with IE (although I tried it in chrome), but that was a while ago and so it may now work in modern browsers

Comment: You're right, `dataset` won't work in IE10 and lower. You'd have to use `getAttribute('data-weight')` for older browsers.

Comment: Is there a way to add a "check/uncheck all" button which will  also automatically compute the price and weight? Or should I ask this as another topic?

Comment: There is indeed, and it's already been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537609/jquery-checkbox-check-all

Answer (score 0):

You have few issues:

- You redeclare `add` variable
- you have typo in `total1` it should be `totwgt`
- you don't have element with `payment-w` id
- instead of `this.wgt` you should use `this.getAttribute('bweight')`

https://jsfiddle.net/u8bsjegk/6/